# How to fix: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm training a LSTM and I'm defining parameters and regression layer. I get the error in the title with this code:

```
 lstm_cells = [
    tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=num_nodes[li],
                            state_is_tuple=True,
                            initializer= tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
                           )
 for li in range(n_layers)]

drop_lstm_cells = [tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(
    lstm, input_keep_prob=1.0,output_keep_prob=1.0-dropout, state_keep_prob=1.0-dropout
) for lstm in lstm_cells]
drop_multi_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(drop_lstm_cells)
multi_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(lstm_cells)

w = tf.get_variable('w',shape=[num_nodes[-1], 1], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
b = tf.get_variable('b',initializer=tf.random_uniform([1],-0.1,0.1))
```

I'm using tensorflow2 and I have already read the https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate guide and I think almost everything on the net.
But I'm not able to solve it.
How can I do it?

Comment: The `tf.contrib` module has been deprecated in TF 2.0

Comment: Yes, but how can I solve it without using tf.contrib? Do you have any suggestion or link where I can search on?

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs because the `contrib` module has been removed from version 2 of tensorflow. There are two solutions to this problem:

1. You can delete the current package and install one of the Series 1 versions.
2. You can use this command, which is also compatible with the version two package: Use `tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell` instead of `tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell` and use `tf.initializers.GlorotUniform ()` instead of `tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer ()` in other command which include rnn you can use `tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell`.

Answer (score 2):

```
tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell -> tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell or tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell

tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper -> tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper or tf.keras.layers.DropOut

tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell -> tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell or tf.keras.layers.RNN
```

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it doesn't work. Thank you though!

Comment: You should update your question with details about why these do not work...

Comment: You are right sorry. This is the error that I have with the first form you suggested: "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v1.compat' has no attribute 'v1' ". Instead, the second form maybe works but I have problem with the initializer: "initializer= tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()". There is the tf.contrib module so it doesn't work. What do you suggest?

Comment: @RobertoBuzzini Looks like RNN now only available in tf.keras. I am having the same problem like you and after searching a lot I didn't see any single case where someone is using RNN directly from tensorflow 2. So, your only option probably tf.keras.layers.RNN. See here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RNN

Answer (score 0):

`tf.contrib` has moved out of TF starting TF 2.0 alpha.
Take a look at these tf 2.0 release notes https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha0
You can upgrade your TF 1.x code to TF 2.x using the `tf_upgrade_v2` script
https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/upgrade